# Solutions to a system of linear equation are proportional to the minors of characteristic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

We have a system of n linear equations, $$(k_{ik}-\omega^2m_{ik} )A_k = 0\tag{1}$$
where $k_{ik}$ and $m_{ik}$ are known, $1\geq i,k\geq n$, and we want to solve it for $A_k$. We also want the solutions to be non-zero, therefore $$det(k_{ik}-\omega^2m_{ik})=0\tag{2}$$ (thinking of it as of n by n matrix).
We are also given that all the roots $\omega_{\alpha}$ of the characteristic equation (2) are all different.

I have to show that now it follows (from the fact that all the roots $w_\alpha$ of the characteristic equation are different) that the coefficients $A_k$ are proportional to the minors of the determinant (2) with $\omega = \omega_\alpha$.

All I can see is n=2 or n=3 with "brute force" calculations, i.e. if $M = \left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\ c&d\end{array}\right)$ then $M\textbf{x} = 0$ (where $detM=0$) is solved by
$$\textbf{x} = \left(\begin{array}{c}
\det(b) \\ 
-\det(a)
\end{array}\right)
= \left(\begin{array}{c}
b \\
-a
\end{array}\right).$$ and for $M = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&c \\ 
d&e&f \\
g&h&i
\end{array}\right)$ the solution with minors is
$$\textbf{x} = \left(\begin{array}{c}
\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}b&c\\ e&f\end{array}\right) \\
-\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&c\\ d&f\end{array}\right) \\
\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\ d&e\end{array}\right)
\end{array}\right).$$

How can I prove that I can find such solution (proportional to minors) for any $n$?
Any help will be appreciate :)